# WindowSize can not be set when windows is maximized

Tags: front-end

Below code can set the window size of current notebook

```
SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[], WindowSize -> Scaled[0.8], 
 WindowMargins -> {{0, 0}, {0, 0}}]
```

However, I found that if the window is maximized, this line of code does not work. See

[image]

How to resize maximized window programmetically?

Comment: If you use "F12" to get "FullScreen" then it works. However, if you use the button at right top, then it is Windows that does the drawing and your code does not work.

Comment: @DanielHuber Ok~ but I think pressing "F12" is not an ordinary operation :)

Comment: "F12" is equivalent to the MMA menu "Window"->"FullScreen"

Comment: @DanielHuber Yeah, I know. I mean at least for me, I do not use "FullScreen" mode at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For some reason, switching the window frame type first seems to work. (In 12.1)

```
myFrame = CurrentValue[WindowFrame];
SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[], WindowFrame -> "Normal"]
SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[], WindowFrame -> "Generic"]
SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[], WindowFrame -> myFrame, 
 WindowMargins -> {{0, Automatic}, {Automatic, 0}}, 
 WindowSize -> Scaled[0.8]]
```

Comment: Great! This works. Thank you so much.